# Receive an unexpected symbol error in my PLSQL query

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE SQLTIME.SY_CURR_CODE
(
  CURRENCY_CODE    VARCHAR2(3 BYTE)             NOT NULL,
  DES1             VARCHAR2(30 BYTE)            NOT NULL,
  CURRENCY_SYMBOL  VARCHAR2(3 BYTE)             NOT NULL
)
```

I want to create a query that will be used in a drop down that will show the the description for each currency code. I have search online for some help, but I cannot get around the following error:

> [Error] PLS-00103 (6342: 88): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ")"
>   when expecting one of the following:
>    * & = - + ; < / > at in is mod remainder not rem  <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like like2 like4

Here is my code:

```
<TR>
    <TD></TD>
    <TD></TD>
    <TD CLASS="tablelabel">Base Currency</TD>
    <TD class="reqlabel1">');
        vSQl := 'select toValueText(a.code, a.descr) from 
            (select currency_code code, des1 descr '||'from sy_curr_code ') a ';
        htp_dropdown(pvSql => vSQL,
        pvName => 'pvcurrencycode',
        pvDefVal => null,
        pvEvent => 'style="width:200px" class="reqinput1" tabindex=33 id="pvcurrencycode"');
        htp.p('
    </TD>
</tr>
```

Comment: databases don't have "dropdowns", and you haven't mentioned WHERE this dropdown would occur... so no help for you.

Comment: sorry first time here

Comment: I think your quote before before your `)` in the following needs to be removed. `') a ';` Does that fix your problem? Also what are the pipes in quotes for?

Comment: @ josh , omg thanks first time working with databases, do im new to this and yes it works,i think i can give you points but dont know how to

Comment: I have wrote an official answer, but as for my prior question, what is `'||'` for?

Comment: As for giving me points, there is an option to accept an answer via a checkmark by the answer. Welcome to StackOverflow by the way, please visit the [help] if you havent already.

Comment: thanks , i have another question it involves this same issue, do i make a new question or do i edit it?

Comment: for example i want dropdown to show from a another table s_sales_center the column currency_code and also to show the other options from the table sy_curr_code(like it does in this code)

Comment: You should always make another question if it is not the same exact thing; otherwise, you make this question confusing and could possibly invalidate answers. However, please be sure to try to figure out the problem for yourself first. It is sometimes frowned upon when people post every part of their project and it looks like they just want others to do it for them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to have an extra quote in your query. The following should work for you:

```
vSQl := 'select toValueText(a.code, a.descr) from 
        (select currency_code code, des1 descr '||'from sy_curr_code ) a ';
```

Note the quote before your closing parenthesis has been removed.

Comment: @user2892179 By the way, I dont really understand what you are using the `'||'` for. It seems like it should be removed to me; but, I have no experience in PLSQL specifically so I could be wrong. :)